# Populate DataTables from json (not from ajax)

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am trying to populate datatable on click.
Initially I have this configuration:

```
var json = [];
var shippingMethodsTable = $("#shipping-methods-table").DataTable({
    'data': json,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "ShippingMethodId" },
        { "data": "MethodName"},
        { "data": "Code"},
        { "data": "ShippingTypeName" },
        { "data": "MaxWeight" }
    ]
});
```

After I click button I have json object of arrays:

```
json = ko.toJSON(data.shippingMethods); // I am using knockout.js to populate it
```

Result:

```
"[{"ShippingMethodId":2,"MethodName":"Priority Mail","Code":null,"ShippingTypeName":"Parcel","MaxWeight":"70 lbs"},{"ShippingMethodId":4,"MethodName":"Priority Mail Express","Code":null,"ShippingTypeName":"Parcel","MaxWeight":"70 lbs"},{"ShippingMethodId":5,"MethodName":"First-Class Mail","Code":null,"ShippingTypeName":"Parcel","MaxWeight":"13 oz"},{"ShippingMethodId":6,"MethodName":"USPS Retail Ground","Code":null,"ShippingTypeName":"Parcel","MaxWeight":"70 lbs"},{"ShippingMethodId":8,"MethodName":"Media Mail","Code":null,"ShippingTypeName":"Parcel","MaxWeight":"70 lbs"}]"
```

And then I am trying to update datatable

```
shippingMethodsTable.clear();
shippingMethodsTable.rows.add('{"data":' + json + '}');
shippingMethodsTable.draw();
```

But getting an error:  `Requested unknown parameter 'ShippingMethodId' for row 0, column 0`

Comment: It looks like you're adding the entire JSON to each row, other than adding the relevant data to each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) expects array of object, rather than object.
So, try

```
shippingMethodsTable.clear();
shippingMethodsTable.rows.add(json);
shippingMethodsTable.draw();
```

instead.